# Unable to run turtle class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, turtle-graphics

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yashg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/turtle2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "C:/Users/yashg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32\turtle.py", line 18, in <module>
    draw_square()
  File "C:/Users/yashg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32\turtle.py", line 3, in draw_square
    window=turtle.Screen()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Screen'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your script other than `turtle.py`. Otherwise it prevents import of standard library `turtle`; your module is searched first and imported instead of standard library one.

Also make sure there's no `turtle.pyc` remained in the directory `C:\Users\yashg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32`.

Comment: Hi, thnx for the swift reply
But even after changing the name, I am getting the same error.
As u can see in the above code, I am using turtle2.py

Comment: @yash_g5, You have `turtle.py`, (check `turtle.pyc` too) in the same directory. (according to the given traceback in the question)

Comment: thnx.. i got it running... :)